imGui cloning master or docking repo from github even after forking
when cloning directly from cmd or even github desktop the imGui repo (both master and dokcing branch):
git clone repo -b master

...I get this error:
Cloning into 'myapp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 58006, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (192/192), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (84/84), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 30 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

